# Difference between writing data in memory directly and using asm instruction

Tags: memory, assembly

I am reading the Linux kernel. I am curious about the way to write data in memory.

In some part of drivers, they use the `writel()` function defined in `asm/io.h` and in definition of that function, they use the `movnti` instruction - actually I don't understand what this instruction means except it is a kind of `mov` instruction.

Anyway, when writing data in memory, what's the difference between using `writel()` and directly writing in memory, *e.g.* `**address = data;`.

Here is the case:

```
static inline void __writel(__u32 val, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    volatile __u32 __iomem *target = addr;
    asm volatile("movnti %1,%0"
             : "=m" (*target)
             : "r" (val) : "memory");
}
```

and this is another case:

```
*(unsigned int*)(MappedAddr+pageOffset) = result;
```

Comment: Well this instruction is used to minimize cache pollution and it cannot be done with a simple '=' operator in c. movnti: "Moves the doubleword integer in the source operand (second operand) to the destination operand (first operand) using a non-temporal hint to minimize cache pollution during the write to memory. The source operand is a general-purpose register. The destination operand is a 32-bit memory location."

Comment: http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc195.htm

Comment: @john Thanks for reply. so you mean that "movnti" instruction is almost same with "mov" and care about cache pollution. right?

Comment: @Devolus Oh Thanks! I didn`t find it before.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have read. But what is it used at i don't know... My kernel is not very advanced atm and i don't know how to use these in a kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand [this](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc195.htm) correctly then using the `moventi` instruction will minimise the impact on the processor's data caches. Using `*(unsigned int*)(MappedAddr+pageOffset) = result;` instead leaves the the compiler free to choose whichever `move` instruction it likes, and its likely to choose one that causes the cache line to be pulled into the cache. Which is probably not what you want if you're interacting with a memory mapped device.

Comment: Oh. You mentioned what I want to know. Thanks!

Comment: @torak, Ah, finally I understand what this is really doing. I was thinking about this and just from the link it was unclear what the intention of this code is, but the hint with memory mapped IO makes it clear now. +1

Answer (score 2):

`writel` looks like it's intended for memory mapped IO, there are a few things to support this, first the use of the `volatile` pointer (which prevents optimization such as reordering calls or optimizing them out among other things) and the non-temproal instruction (IO writes/reads shouldn't be cached) and of course the `iomem` annotation seems to support this too.

Comment: `__iomem` is not a variable, it's a `sparse` annotation.

Comment: In the first place, the `write()` function writes to a file, not to memory. Just sayin'...

Comment: @FrankKotler: this is Linux kernel's `__writel()`, not userspace `write()`

Comment: Okay. My mistake. I was "reading too fast" too! Sorry 'bout that.